# Change color of button in a ink splash manner

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to change the color of a button after the ink splash. To elaborate I would like the color of the button to change the way it does in the ink splash, with the difference of the color of the ink splash actually changes the color of the button.

[image]

Like the gif above the color of the button changes when the user presses the button due to the ink splash, but when the user stops pressing the button it goes back to its normal color. I am aware that I can just change the color of the actual button in the `onPressed` method, but that does not give me the effect of the splash which I desire. An example of that could be:

[image]

It's a bit hard for me to explain it, now that I am unable to actually show what I mean. Feel free to comment for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use flat button for such highlight color effect :

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: onPressed,
  highlightColor: Colors.blue.shade300, // your highlight color here
  color: Colors.blue, // normal button color here
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
  child: child
),
```

Comment: I want the color to change (and stay changed) in a splash color manner. The way the color temporarily changes when the user pressed the button.

Comment: this is what that code does whenever user tap on button it changes color to `highlightColor` and when remove back to normal as in second gif